# What is the difference between board level and Soc level information in DTS(device tree source) and DTSI?

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot, device-tree, petalinux, fpga

For Device Tree Blob it says several boards can use one SoC so the SoC level information is included in board level in order not to be duplicated(DTSI is included in DTS). So

1.What is considered to be BOARD and PLATFORM(difference)? 
2. Is there a usable board without any SoC, FPGA or stuff like that?
3. How can several boards be connected to each other? (pins or ..??)

Answer (score 1):

A platform in this context is a set of different boards that are similar, e.g. PC motherboards are different, but together they form a platform that can be treated uniformly. A SoC is a System on a Chip, i.e. a CPU and associated peripheral circuits are integrated on one silicon chip. The same SoC can be used on different boards designs, in which case they all have the same SoC in common, so it makes sense to have the description of the SiC in a separate file. "Several boards" refers to several different board designs, not several interconnected boards.

Comment: So I got it wrong and one SoC can't be used by several boards at the SAME time?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. One SoC cannot be *shared* by several boards, but of course you can use the same SoC on several boards, and even connect the boards together. It all depends on the design. I was just pointing out that the motivation for putting the SoC description in a dtsi file is that different board designs can reuse the dtbi file. That's what is meant by "several boards".

Comment: I got it, thank you very much, just have a few more questions about interconnected boards, and Device tree. Can I ask you? would be very grateful ))

Comment: Device Tree descriptions are for pretty primitive stuff, like memory addresses, i/o addresses, interrupts, I/o pins, etc., and as such are not really applicable over board crossings, which are much more complex and diverse than can be described by Device Tree. So DT files typically encompass only one board.

Comment: Of course, if the interconnect only conveys a shared address and data bus, then the boards are, from the software's point of view, one logical board. It all depends on the design at hand.

Comment: I have come across DMA engine and channel  properties in a node in DT:  `dmas = <&dma_apbx 8>,<&dma_apbx 9>` and  `dma-names = "rx", "tx"` It says that "**rx**" reffers to "**<&dma_apbx 8>**" and **tx** refers to **<&dma_apbx 9>** respectively. **I want to know if "dmas" can have more than two values?? or its always two - the engine and channel?**